# Eliminate port number from ulr in tomcat

Tags: apache

**For example my url is "http://example.com:8080", I have to eliminate the 8080, I have tried the following code in server.xml file.**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

replaced 8080 to 80 but not working.

please help me on this issue

Comment: What exactly did not work? Did tomcat not start or is it still listening on port 8080? Changing the port to "80" should do what you asked for. Maybe another process is already listening on port 80. On Windows you can check with netstat -aon. On Linux with netstat -tupagn.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `http://example.com` to be the URL you type in the browser? Then you either need another component like another webserver on same host (as reverse-proxy) or your Tomcat has to listen on port 80.

Also, if you redirect to another port, your webserver has to listen to that specific port, in your case 8443, if you want to use that.

My recommendation in such a case is to use an minimal setup of Apache as a reverse-proxy. Besides the standard modules you'd have to enable `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_http` and if you need SSL-handling also `mod_ssl`.

Then your Apache listens to port 80 and proxies all requests to the Tomcat-backend on whatever-port Tomcat should listen to. Both can run on the same server, no need for an additional VM/hardware.

You wouldn't even need a vhost on Apache if you only use that for the proxy functionality:

```
Listen 80

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://tomcat-url.com
ProxyPassReverse / http://tomcat-url.com
```

Just make sure you have the mentioned modules active and the code above in your config.

Let me know if you'd like to go that route and have further questions :)